# How do I fix the errors in this Airtable script that calculates the time left in a quarter to achieve a number?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, variable-assignment, airtable

I'm trying to write a personal script for an Airtable extension that does the following:

1. **Calculates progress towards a quarterly writing goal:** This sums the numeric values from a field in a specific view.
2. **The amount left that I need to write:** This is not a number
   available in my base.
3. Return how many articles per week I need to write to achieve my goal in time.
4. Return the number of *weekdays* it will take per article
   remaining to achieve the goal in time.

Here's the script so far:

```js
/*This function does the following: 
1. Calculates total articles in a view
2. Calculates progress towards quarterly goal
3. Returns articles left to achieve goal */

let table = base.getTable("Writing Assignments");
let view = table.getView("My Production Count");

// count the articles and calculate percentage of quarterly goal:
let result = await view.selectRecordsAsync({ fields: ["Article count"] });
let runningTotal = 0;
let minGoal = 18;
let maxGoal = 24;
for (let record of result.records) {
  // this calculates percentage of total and rounds to the nearest integer:
  runningTotal += record.getCellValue("Article count");
}
const progress = Math.round((runningTotal * 100) / minGoal);

// calculate articles remaining:
var remaining = minGoal - runningTotal;



//This function counts the time remaining in the quarter

var weeks;
var days;
var quarter;

/* 
  Now we write a function that:
    1. Figures out the current date
    2. Compares that to the end date of each quarter, to figure out what quarter we're in
    3. Updates those empty spots in the page with the time left in the current quarter
*/

const getTimeUntilEndOfQuarter = () => {
  /* Here's the current time */
  const now = new Date();

  /* 
    Here's the end date of each quarter.
    Notice that I'm using the current year from "now",
    so we won't have to worry about doing any manual updating each year.
  */
  const Q1 = new Date("April 1 " + now.getFullYear());
  const Q2 = new Date("July 1 " + now.getFullYear());
  const Q3 = new Date("October 1 " + now.getFullYear());
  const Q4 = new Date("January 1 " + (now.getFullYear() + 1));

  /* 
    Now let's compare the current time to each of those end dates.
    Once we've found the quarter we're in, update the page to say which one,
    then update the "currentQuarter" value to be that quarter's end date.
  */
  let currentQuarter;
  if (now > Q3) {
    currentQuarter = Q4;
    quarter = "Q4";
  } else if (now > Q2) {
    currentQuarter = Q3;
    quarter = "Q3";
  } else if (now > Q1) {
    currentQuarter = Q2;
    quarter = "Q2";
  } else {
    currentQuarter = Q1;
    quarter = "Q1";
  }

  /* 
    Here, we get the number of milliseconds between now and the end of the quarter,
    then we do some math to get that in days instead, 
    because that'll be a number that actually makes sense.
  */
  const timeLeft = currentQuarter.getTime() - now.getTime();
  var totalDaysLeft = Math.ceil(timeLeft / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

  /*
    Divide that number by 7 and round down to get the number of weeks,
    then get the modulo of that number and the total number of days to get the remaining days
  */
  var weeksLeft = Math.floor(totalDaysLeft / 7);
  var daysLeft = totalDaysLeft % 7;

  // Remove weekends

  var totalWeekdaysLeft = function subtractWeekends(totalDaysLeft) {
    days -= weeksLeft * 2;

    // Handle special cases
    var startDay = now.getDay();
    var endDay = currentQuarter.getDay();

    // Remove weekend not previously removed.   
    if (startDay - endDay > 1) {
      days -= 2;
    }
    // Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
    if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6) {
      days--;
    }
    // Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
    if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0) {
      days--;
    }
  }


  // Calculate articles to submit per week and days needed to write each article to achieve goal:

  var daysPerArticle = totalWeekdaysLeft / remaining;
  var articlesPerWeek = weeksLeft / remaining;




  /*
    Now let's get those numbers on the page
  */

  /*
    If the number isn't 1, make sure we say "weeks" or "days" plural
  */


  const weeksPlural = weeksLeft == 1 ? "week" : "weeks";
  const daysPlural = totalWeekdaysLeft == 1 ? "day" : "days";
};



/* 
  Remember that function we just wrote? Run it! 
*/
getTimeUntilEndOfQuarter();

/*
  And run it again every 15 minutes
*/


output.markdown(`
# Status

## Progress toward quarterly goal:  

![](https://geps.dev/progress/${progress})

${progress} % to ${minGoal} articles

## Days per article to hit goal:
${daysPerArticle} ${daysPlural} per article 

## Articles per week to hit goal:
${articlesPerWeek} ${weeksPlural} per week 

`);
```

**The issue I'm having:** It seems the way I'm declaring variables seems to make the math I'm trying to calculate not possible, since it keeps returning errors.

I'm pretty new at JavaScript, so some of the code below is based on tinkering with Airtable's examples, some code a friend helped me with to dynamically calculate days and weeks remaining in a quarter, and some Stack Overflow examples.

There is probably more things I've messed up on, but I don't enough knowledge to know yet.  Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: can you provide the error's please

Comment: line 111: daysPerArticle is declared but its value is never read
line 112: articlesPerWeek is declared but its value is never read

Comment: is the error fixed ?